# How to create an api dynamic route in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, rest, next.js

I am trying to add a dynamic route to the `api` folder for `GET` request.
In this scenario it works fine
`api/[product]`

```
const baseUrl ='https://myUrl'
 const { product } = req.query
  const url = `${baseUrl}/${product}`
```

And then testing `http://localhost:3000/api/phone` in `Postman` returns the correct result. So far it is fine.
Then, instead of fetching the `api` by product, I want my dynamic property to be filter values.
 Filter syntax provided by particular `api` looks like this `?$filter=name eq 'Milk'`.
Filtering on frontend works fine when I test it in postman or in browser.

```
https://myUrl/phone?$filter=name eq 'iphone'
```

Now I try to do exactly the same as above, now in `api` folder. But it returns `404 This page could not be found.`.

`api/[productType]`

```
const baseUrl ='https://myUrl/phone?$filter'
 const { productType } = req.query
  const url = `${baseUrl}=${productType}`
```

In `Postman` I test it so:

```
`http://localhost:3000/api/phone=name-eq-'iphone'`
```

And get `404` response.
How to fix this issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not an expert but, i think the problem is having 2 dynamic routes in the same folder `[product]` and `[productType]`.

Try a different structure inside API folder like nested dynamic routes or something like that.

Comment: Hey @CodeAlb thanks for the answer. That would make sense, if this url would't work: 'https://myUrl/phone?$filter=name eq 'iphone'. But this work, and I assume, that since it works on frontend, there must be some workaround, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a demo at https://github.com/vercel-support/so-71663454-nextjs-route-poc with

```
// /api/[productType]

export default function handler (req, res) {
  const baseUrl ='https://myUrl/phone?$filter'

  const { productType } = req.query
  
  const url = `${baseUrl}=${productType}`
  res.json({ productType, query: req.query, url })
}
```

If you visit the link using [https://so-71663454-nextjs-route-poc.vercel-support.app/api/phone=name-eq-'iphone'](https://so-71663454-nextjs-route-poc.vercel-support.app/api/phone=name-eq-%27iphone%27)

You should be able to see the following result:

```
{
  "productType": "phone=name-eq-'iphone'",
  "query": {
    "productType": "phone=name-eq-'iphone'"
  },
  "url": "https://myUrl/phone?$filter=phone=name-eq-'iphone'"
}
```